# How to get screen height in LWUIT out of height reserved for MenuBar and TitleBar?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to get the height and width of the screen which I could draw objects on. It's the space which is other than the the MenuBar (the footer containing commands) and other than the TitleBar. 
 
**TIP:** I know that `Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight()` returns the height of the screen but this is for the full sceen. So how could I, at least, know the height of the MenuBar and TitleBar to substract them from this height ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer for those who are interested: 

To get the height of TitleBar: `Form.getTitleComponent().getPreferredH()` 
To get the height of AddressBar: `Form.getSoftButton(0).getParent().getPreferredH()` 

So the answer of my question is:

```
Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() 
        - form.getTitleComponent().getPreferredH() 
        - (getSoftbuttonCount() < 1) ? 0 : form.getSoftButton(0).getParent().getPreferredH()
```

Comment: This answer isn't quite correct. You need to getSoftbuttonCount() and make sure it is bigger than 1. Furthermore you need to getTitleArea() which might be bigger than the title component itself. See the code in Dialog.java that does pretty much that.

Comment: Code is updated with your correction about **getSoftbuttonCount**, but i cannot find the method **getTitleArea** which you mentioned in **Form** class ? I'm using LWUIT 1.4, is it in later versions or I'm searching in the wrong class ?

Comment: Its part of the 1.5 release, you can use the current code for 1.4 only.